# How to enable datasharing in Redshift cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to create a datashare in Redshift by following this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/datashare-overview.html). When I type this command:

`CREATE DATASHARE datashare_name`

I get this message:

`ERROR:  CREATE DATASHARE is not enabled.`

I also tried to make it using console, but same issue.
So how to enable data sharing in Redshift ?

Answer (score 7):

From the documents:[here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/considerations.html)
Data sharing via datashare is only available for ra3 instance types
The document lists ra3.16xlarge, ra3.4xlarge, and ra3.xlplus instance types for producer and consumer clusters.

So, if I were in your place - I would first go back and check my instance type. If still not sure, drop a simple CS ticket and ask them if anything has changed recently & documentation is not updated

Comment: you saved a lot of time for me, thanks :-)

Comment: They really don't communicate this all that well in the UI or the error messages. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the beautiful world of Redshift @tadman